# What do you call the act of pretending to be working so you can relax a bit at work?

Tags: word-request

You know sometimes at work, you finish something and then you just relax a bit, because you don't want to get burdened with another ticket. Is there a word for such action? I am not saying people should do this, but they do this.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you think this very specific meaning would have a single word definition in English (for example is there a single word in your native languge?)

Comment: Not a word but a phrase: _to go through the motions_. Not exactly what you asked about but close enough imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a word for it. It seems to be more common as a *single* word in British English, and (seemingly) as a two-word phrase in US English. I know I hear the two-word phrase quite often in Canada.

[**Skive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skive)

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   verb (1)
>   *British informal*
>   : to avoid work or school by staying away or by leaving without permission
>   // … 71 per cent said rewards for good ideas and punctuality would make them work harder and not *skive* …
>   — *South Wales Evening Post*
>   // Tam is 15 and he's *skiving* school.
>   — Julie Mccaffrey
>   —often used with *off*
>   // I once worked in a hospital garden where my workmate *skived off* every day with "backache" and disappeared to work on his car at home.— Louis De Bernières
>
> verb (2)
>    : to cut off (a material, such as leather or rubber) in thin layers or pieces : PARE
>
> **Examples of *skive* in a Sentence**
>   Verb (2)
>   // He works for his mother and feels he can *skive off* whenever he feels like it.
>   // She *skived off* school twice last month.

Honestly, I'd never heard the single-word version before looking it up. I'd assumed I'd find it listed in the dictionary under *skive off*.

While it can be used in the sense of skipping work altogether, I often hear it used for people who are *at work* but not actually doing anything productive. (Such as playing games on their computers.)